# How to use jBPM 6 as JBOSS EAP module?

Tags: java, jboss, jbpm

I have a number of web applications under JBOSS EAP 6.2 which use jBPM 6.

jBPM jars take about 20MB in each WEB-INF/lib so I decided to move them into a separate JBoss module. After that I have issues with classloading because jBPM module's classloader tries to load classes by name defined in web applications and fails to do that (ClassNotFound errors).

So my question is there a way to use jBPM 6 as a JBoss module OR is there a way to load jBPM module's classes using web applications classloaders?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are modules containing core jars available out-of-the-box:
http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/kie/kie-eap-distributions-bpms-layer/

The slim workbench war using these modules is available here:
http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/kie/kie-eap-distributions-bpms-webapp/

Note that the latest snapshots are targeted to eap 6.3.0.

Comment: I have already moved jbpm to a separate jboss module.
Will your solution help me to get rid of my problem when jbpm module's classloader can't find classes defined in web applications when searhing them by name.